# Why can't I reference a class in another namespace in another project within the same solution?

Tags: c#

I have created another namespace in another project but within the same solution. When I type using this other namespace it shows up. But I cannot see any public class within that namespace. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the type is public, this sounds as simple as a missing *project reference* between the two. Right click references and add a new reference, but watch that references shouldn't become circular (i.e. A <===> B, or A ===> B ===> C ===> A). Actually, the VS IDE doesn't let you do this, but it can be done (accidentally or purposefully) via the command-line tools.

Answer (score 4):

You have to

- reference the exporting assembly in the importing project
- define 1 or more public classes in the exporting project.